# Does boosting use more fuel?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

Does boosting with a vehicule use more fuel? (Pressing shift makes your car go a little bit faster)

Side question: If it does, what is better for distance? Using the boost and going a little bit faster but consuming more, or not using the boost and going slower but farther?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes boosting consumes fuel faster in all vehicles that can boost. I would say if you want to get maximum distance, then do not boost.  Reading [this Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PUBATTLEGROUNDS/comments/69r8vr/all_about_vehicles_stats_fuel_and_strategies/) seems to show that you get about double the distance without boosting when observing across a finite fuel range:

> BOOSTED, 1 MINI BAR = ~500m
>
> NO BOOST, 1 MINI BAR = ~1km

Comment: Oh my, its double. Ok so boosting is really not worth it if you have a long way to go and dont want to be car hopping.